# Checkbox checked property is not working in JQUERY Datatable column

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a `jquery datatable` in which first coloumn is `checkboxes`.In the application while editing ,i need to display the selected items as thier `checkbox` **checked**.I am getting the data from `ajax response`.Data binding is working fine,but the `checked` attribute isn't.

here is my code:

```
custAct.success = function (status) {
       try {
               var response = JSON.parse(status);
               activityCust.clear().draw();

  for (var i = 0; i < response.length - 1 ; i++) 
      {
activityCust.row.add({ 0: '<input class="checkboxCust" checked=' + response[i].IsSelected + '  value="' + response[i].ID + '" data-id="' + response[i].ID + '" type="checkbox" />', 1: response[i].Name, 2: response[i].Hours }).draw();    
      }

catch(ex)
{
}
```

`Html` code:

```
<table class="gridTableActivityCust hover">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>Select</th>
                                    <th>Activity Name</th>
                                    <th>Hours</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                                @foreach (var item in Model.Activities)
                                {
                                    <tr data-id="@item.ActId">
                                        <td>
                                            <input class='checkboxCust' disabled="@item.Enabled" checked="@item.IsSelected" value="@item.ActId" data-id="@item.ActId" type='checkbox' />
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            @item.ActivityName
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            @item.Hours
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                }
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
```

here is the `json` response:

```
[
  {
    "ID": 1,
    "Name": "Activity 1",
    "Description": "nc",
    "Hours": 2,
    "Remove": false,
    "Active": false,
    "IsSelected": false,
    "Disabled": true
  },
  {
    "ID": 2,
    "Name": "Activity 2",
    "Description": "lkn",
    "Hours": 3,
    "Remove": false,
    "Active": true,
    "IsSelected": false,
    "Disabled": false
  },
  {
    "ID": 3,
    "Name": "Activity 3",
    "Description": "lkk",
    "Hours": 2,
    "Remove": false,
    "Active": false,
    "IsSelected": false,
    "Disabled": true
  },
  {
    "ID": 4,
    "Name": "Activity 4",
    "Description": "kjhj",
    "Hours": 3,
    "Remove": false,
    "Active": true,
    "IsSelected": false,
    "Disabled": false
  },
  {
    "ID": 5,
    "Name": "Activity 5",
    "Description": "mn",
    "Hours": 7,
    "Remove": false,
    "Active": true,
    "IsSelected": true,
    "Disabled": false
  },
  {
    "ID": 6,
    "Name": "Activity 6",
    "Description": "kj",
    "Hours": 5,
    "Remove": false,
    "Active": true,
    "IsSelected": false,
    "Disabled": false
  },
  {
    "ID": 7,
    "Name": "Activity 7",
    "Description": "hj",
    "Hours": 8,
    "Remove": false,
    "Active": false,
    "IsSelected": false,
    "Disabled": true
  },
  {
    "ID": 8,
    "Name": "gdfg",
    "Description": "dgdfg",
    "Hours": 4.4,
    "Remove": false,
    "Active": true,
    "IsSelected": false,
    "Disabled": false
  }
]
```

In the response only **Activity 5** is selected.But in the UI all the checkboxes are getting selected.

Screenshot:

[image: img]

In this case only Activity 5 should be checked.

Comment: Can you share the form. Just assuming that name of checkboxes may be same.

Comment: @AditShah I've updated my question.

Comment: @AditShah checkboxes names are same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
activityCust.row.add({ 0: '<input class="checkboxCust" ' + response[i].IsSelected? checked="checked":""+'  value="' + response[i].ID + '" data-id="' + response[i].ID + '" type="checkbox" />', 1: response[i].Name, 2: response[i].Hours }).draw();
```

What you are basically doing is writing `checked=true` or `checked=false` in your HTML from the JSON response. The valid HTML code is `checked="checked"` for a checked checkbox, the unchecked checkboxes do not have the checked attribute at all.